# Informix: .NET driver: default datetime format

Tags: .net, datetime, informix

I am using Informix .NET driver in my winforms app and am populating a data grid with a stored procedure resultset. The weird thing is that the datetime year to second(format set by the stored proc and returned) column is being displayed as datetime year to minute with AM/PM. Does the .net driver change/apply formatting to the resultset's datetime column?

Comment: None of the formats with AM/PM are produced by Informix unless it is specifically commanded to do so.  So something in the environment is making it happen. Whether that is an environment variable or a value in the connection string or something that is done on the client side of the Informix drivers is going to be harder to track down.  Locale settings could be relevant too

Comment: Informix precedence for date formats, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1832.htm , in my case, I am setting the CLIENT_LOCALE to en_US.819 and DBDATE and GL_DATE are not set on my end(client). Am I correct in assuming that the en_US.819 environment variable is what is affecting the datetime format? I couldn't find the default format for this encoding.

Answer (score 2):

With .NET the date format is usually controlled by your localization settings (CultureInfo), it is not done by the provider.

In the code below I'm using CultureInfo() to specify "en-US" and "en-GB" formats:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using IBM.Data.Informix;


class sample {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

     IfxConnection conn;
     try {

        conn = new IfxConnection("Server=ids1410;Database=sysmaster");
        conn.Open();    
        IfxCommand cmmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmmd.CommandText = "SELECT current::datetime year to second";
        IfxDataReader drdr;
        drdr = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
        drdr.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("GetIfxDateTime:\t\t"+drdr.GetIfxDateTime(0)); 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        Console.WriteLine("GetDateTime (en-US):\t"+drdr.GetDateTime(0)); 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
        Console.WriteLine("GetDateTime (en-GB):\t"+drdr.GetDateTime(0)); 
        
        conn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
   }
}
```

That will result in

```
D:\Infx\cs>csc.exe /R:%INFORMIXDIR%\bin\netf40\IBM.Data.Informix.dll /nologo datetime.cs

D:\Infx\cs>datetime
GetIfxDateTime:         2020-10-20 09:30:32
GetDateTime (en-US):    10/20/2020 9:30:32 AM
GetDateTime (en-GB):    20/10/2020 09:30:32

D:\Infx\cs>
```

You may want to use GetIfxDateTime() instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try out your solution.